# Eloquent Query Cast to Float

Tags: mysql, laravel, casting, eloquent

I have an eloquent query and I want to cast a field as "float". It's a aggregated value, and it returns as a string at the moment, here's an example of the query:

```
$productStats->selectRaw("
    product.id,
    TRIM(product.name) AS item_name,
    SUM(IF(order.order_paid_date BETWEEN '" . $start->timestamp . "' AND '" . $end->timestamp . "' AND order.order_type = 'order' AND (open_count > 0 OR click_count > 0), order_item.total_price, 0)) as revenue,
    COALESCE(CAST(SUM(IF(order.updated_date BETWEEN '" . $start->timestamp . "' AND '" . $end->timestamp . "' AND order.order_type = 'order' AND (open_count > 0 OR click_count > 0), 1, 0)) as SIGNED), 0) / CAST(SUM(IF(order.updated_date BETWEEN '" . $start->timestamp . "' AND '" . $end->timestamp . "' AND order.order_type = 'order', 1, 0)) as SIGNED) AS change_rate
");
```

`revenue` and `change_rate` are currently returned as strings but I'd like them to be float. They are computed values so I can't really add attribute casting to the model.

EDIT: I removed DECIMAL from my query per comment.

Comment: DECIMAL type will be sent as string, even if you use mysqlnd version of the PDO driver, that is done on purpose to prevent the decimal from becoming an unreliable float in PHP

Comment: Thanks, I removed decimal but it's still returned as string!

Comment: You *can* use attribute casting.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir How do I use attribute casting when it's not actually from the model? It's a computed value

Comment: Add `revenue` to your model's `$casts` and the value will be converted to a float when you access it.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir it works! Thank you so much! Do you want to add your answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add them to your model's `$casts`:

```php
protected $casts = [
    'revenue' => 'float',
    'change_rate' => 'float',
];
```